# OnClick event firing but not visibly present in the .aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have these 2 buttons with the following codes

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
<asp:Button ID="btnAuthorize" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" Text="Authorise" />
</div>

<div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
 <asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" OnClick="btnReject_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-danger" Text="Reject" />
</div>
</div>
```

in the .vb File I have these methods.

```
Protected Sub btnReject_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
 notify("Succesfully Rejected", "success")
End Sub

Protected Sub btnAuthorize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAuthorize.Click
  notify("Succesfully Authorized", "success")
End Sub
```

Now both buttons are working as expected but there is no OnClick event on the btnAuthorize in the .aspx page
Why is the btnAuthorize firing the `btnAuthorize_Click` when I do not see the `OnClick="btnAuthorize_Click"` in the .aspx page

Comment: Perhaps you have mistakenly erased the method from HTML markup side. Since the controls generate server side impact, even if you delete the markup from UI part it won't affect. This is still a mystery and MSDN doesn't show why this happens. Now if you write OnClick method in HTML page for btnAuthorize and generate its OnClick event, this new event will override your btnAuthorize_Click and it will show as btnAuthorize_Click1()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your assistance.

I came across the *Handles Clause (Visual Basic) documentation* [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/handles-clause) and I found out that there is a **`handles`** clause in my `.vb` file on the method for the button and that would trigger the `Onclick` event even though in the .aspx file does not have the `OnClick="btnAuthorize_Click"`  call.

So this **`Handles btnAuthorize.Click`** in the `.vb` file fires the event and the `btnReject_Click` does not have the handles clause because it is being called in the `.aspx` file already.

```
Protected Sub btnAuthorize_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAuthorize.Click
  notify("Succesfully Authorized", "success")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

In both cases, you don't need nor want to add the onclick = tag. In fact, that tag will run local javaScript code first and THEN run your server side code.

However, the syntax is wrong, and will not even run on your web site - at least it should not.

for a asp.net button?

The tag is called OnClientClick="MyJavaFunctionName()"

Note that the correct format for the above is the JS function name followed by "()"

If you drop in HTML controls from the tool box, then such controls don't call vb.net server side code at all, and thus you use:

```
        <input id="Button3" type="button" onclick="MyHello()" value="button" /></form>
```

So the tag

```
OnClick="btnReject_Click"
```

Is wrong, and not required. In fact if you run that page, you should get a error if you using the local II server from Visual Studio. And in fact, onClick is wrong, it needs to be onclick   (all lower case).

So, it looks like that was a non ASP.net control at one time, and perhaps you cut + paste, or edited the markup. Either way it is wrong syntax, and if you DID  manage to get the correct syntax, that tag is OnClientClick, and the JavaScript function name has to be followed by a set of () under the quotes.

OnClick is NOT allowed in most asp.net controls.

So, remove that tag - it is ill formed, and IIS web server likely will spit out an error if you try and run that page.

For any asp.net buttons? When you drag + drop from the tool box, or cut + paste in the mark up in the editor, then a event stub is automatically wired up for you and you do NOT need any tags for the server side button click event to run. You do NOT wire up the server side events with the markup tags with asp.net controls.

if you do use the OnClientClick tag, then the local browser JavaScript will run first, then your server side vb.net code will run (if you have any code in the forms click event for that button in the vb editor (server side code).

If you did want to run some local JavaScript, then your button would look like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 text-left">
 <asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" OnClientClick="MyHello()" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-danger" Text="Reject" />
</div>
</div>

    <script>
        function MyHello() {
            alert("my hello run client side");
        }
    </script>
```

If you do the above, then a dialog hello box will popup, and then (if any) code on the server vb.net side will run.